# ios - How to link to another controller from HTML made in the UIWebView?

Tags: ios, ios5

I have some HTML in my UIWebView controller, but I can not seem to find a reference for creating a link and from the link to correctly link to another controller within my app which uses a navigation controller.

What should I put in the href tag of my links in order to go to other controllers?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your controller as delegate of UIWebView and implement method (UIWebViewDelegate)

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType;
```

in your link you can set scheme like this

```
"myscheme:// ... "
```

in implementation of method you should check your scheme like this

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)aWebView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request navigationType:(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{
 BOOL shouldLoad = YES;
    if ([request.URL.scheme isEqualToString:@"myscheme"]) {
         shouldLoad = NO;
         MYViewController *myController = [[MYViewController alloc] init];
         [self.navigationController pushViewController:myController ..];
    }
return shouldLoad;
}
```

Comment: thanks - should the myscheme:// be inside the href="" tag? Is that how it is meant to work?

Comment: You are welcome, yes it should be inside href tag, or if you need use button  <input type=button style="width: 95%; height: 70px; font-size: 20pt; onclick="location.href='myscheme://something'" value="send" />

Comment: I just did this:      <a href="myscheme://advertising" class="buttonStyle">Click me!</a> and that didn't trigger the method call.  Any idea why not? also your button example did not trigger the method call either :(

Comment: how do you load your HTML? do you use loadHTMLString or loadRequest?

Comment: I load the html in viewDidAppear like this:     NSString *htmlFile = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"learn" 
                                                         ofType:@"html"];
    
    NSString* htmlString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:htmlFile encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [theWebView loadHTMLString:htmlString baseURL:nil];

Comment: you should use loadRequest method, issue with encoding you can fix with adding  <HEAD>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"> <HEAD>   tag

Comment: and if you need to edit html programmatically before load it to webView, you can save edited string to file and then load it by url

Comment: do you mean I should load the html in a method called loadRequest? Or something else?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15330/discussion-between-geekedout-and-user1090590)

Answer (score 1):

You need to work with URL Schemes. It's not complicated, but you need to register your app for a custom URL Scheme.

You should be fine with this link: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/ios-sdk-working-with-url-schemes/

Comment: Hi, I didn't mean to have a link to go to another app. I just wanted to go to another controller within my own app.